# Output Labels using sklearn.AffinityPropagation

Tags: machine-learning, bioinformatics, scikit-learn

I've got a set of data that is a distance matrix for 1000 homologous protein sequences.

I've managed to compute the affinity matrix for this (easy calculation: 1 - distance, in my case).

Basically, if the data were viewed in Excel, no header rows, 1st column is sequence name, and then the next 1000 columns are the distance values.

I have modified the code provided on sklearn's Affinity Propagation site. This is what it looks like right now:

```
print __doc__

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import csv

##############################################################################
f = open('ha-sequences-sample-distmat2.csv', 'rU')
csvreader = csv.reader(f)

sequence_names = []
distance_matrix = []
full_data = []

for row in csvreader:
#   print row

    sequence_names.append(row[0])
    distance_matrix.append(row[1:])
    full_data.append(row)

f.close()

distmat = np.array([row for row in distance_matrix]).astype(np.float)

# print distmat

affinity_matrix = np.array([1 - row for row in distmat]).astype(np.float)

full_matrix = zip(sequence_names, affinity_matrix)

# print affinity_matrix, sequence_names




##############################################################################
# Compute Affinity Propagation
af = AffinityPropagation(affinity='precomputed').fit(affinity_matrix)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_

n_clusters_ = len(cluster_centers_indices)

print 'Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_
print "Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(sequence_names, labels)
print "Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(sequence_names, labels)
print "V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(sequence_names, labels)
print "Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f" % \
    metrics.adjusted_rand_score(sequence_names, labels)
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f" %
      metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(sequence_names, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f" %
      metrics.silhouette_score(affinity_matrix, labels, metric='sqeuclidean'))

##############################################################################
# Plot result
import pylab as pl
from itertools import cycle

pl.close('all')
pl.figure(1)
pl.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
    class_members = labels == k
    cluster_center = affinity_matrix[cluster_centers_indices[k]]
    pl.plot(affinity_matrix[class_members, 0], affinity_matrix[class_members, 1], col + '.')
    pl.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
            markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
    for x in affinity_matrix[class_members]:
        pl.plot([cluster_center[0], x[0]], [cluster_center[1], x[1]], col)

pl.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
pl.show()
```

The problem I'm having is this: I can't figure out how to output the sequence names that correspond to each cluster. It'd be nicest if I could output to the shell the sequences that clustered together and displayed the cluster numbers on the plot, but even if I don't display things on the plot, that's cool too.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: you should ask biostars: http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: Totally didn't know about that. Thanks a lot Pierre!

Comment: @Pierre: out of interest (I'm one of the sklearn devs, but not a biologist), are there scikit-learn users active on that site?

Comment: not as far as I know ( I just found http://www.biostars.org/p/46892/ ) , but you might introduce your tool as in http://www.biostars.org/new/post/ as "Post-Type=Tutorial"

Comment: @larsmans, I would really love a bit more documentation on the scikit-learn site on the type of inputs that each algorithm takes, and how to generate those inputs. For example, until I dug through the source code and ran the sample code provided, I didn't know that I could feed in an affinity matrix and set the "affinity" parameter to "pre-computed". I could have saved a day or two of frustration with that kind of documentation.

Comment: @larsmans, I might also add, I was struggling for at least 2 days trying to figure out how I could reformat my multiple sequence alignments into the euclidean (x, y) coordinates that the blob generator example fed... "n_samples, n_features" doesn't really tell me much.

Comment: @ericmjl: I admit the docs for this class could be improved. Feel free to submit a patch. The meaning of `n_samples` and `n_features` is the same throughout the scikit, though, and it's explained in the tutorials.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize there was a tutorial! But I put that down to the fact that I was pointed to scikit-learn by someone who already had the expertise there, and so skipped out on much. Thank you, @larsmans!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your list of sequence names (sequence_names) and a an array of cluster labels (af.labels_). So you can just loop over the array of cluster labels and keep a map from cluster labels list of sequence names. For example

```
#for a simple example, assume the names and cluster labels are predefined
sequence_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
labels = [0,1,1,0]

from collections import defaultdict
clusternames = defaultdict(list)

for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    clusternames[label].append(sequence_names[i])

#clusternames now holds a map from cluster label to list of sequence names
#Print out the label with the list 
for k, v in clusternames.items():
    print k, v
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you, Ando!